# htaccess rewrite old php files to CodeIgniter file

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to redirect old site files toward new CodeIgniter site with `.htaccess`.

So, my old file

```
www.mysite.com/news/new?id=123
```

have to redirect to

```
www.mysite.com/news/new/123
```

For now, my `.htaccess` has inside usually code to remove `index.php` and it works fine.

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
```

But when I try the old file redirect nothing works.
I think the issue's about CodeIgniter, becouse if I make a simple redirect to an external file, like `phpinfo.php` it works fine, but if a try the redirect to `index.php` (of CodeIgniter) it doesn't load `index.php` but try to load other. Also does if I delete `.htaccess` code for `index.php` (see upside).

So,

```
RewriteRule news/new.php phpinfo.php [L]  # it works
```

but

```
RewriteRule news/new.php index.php [L]  # it doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter use REQUEST_URI Apache variable that can not change with RewriteRule and without redirection. So you can use **[_remap](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls)** function in news controller to call your custom method.

Other way that can be doing with htaccess is **[enabling query string](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#enabling-query-strings)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`RewriteRule news/new\?id=(.*)$ index.php/news/new/$1 [L]`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!